# how to disable linter in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, linter

[image]

this linter makes me feel sick to my stomach. I can't concentrate on my program. By the way, I don't use the extension linter.

I tried to disable all my extensions but nothing happened.

Comment: This is not spell checker. This is linter. You can add analytics_option.yaml and add particular rule as ignore.

Comment: Welcome! The IDE looks like VS Code. You should add a tag for the IDE when you're asking a question that has to do with an IDE. Add the tag for whichever IDE this is, please.

Comment: It looks like you named your class incorrectly, and you used new when new has long been made optional.  The lints are trying to tell you to fix your code.  It's not a "spell checker".  It's a serious tool to help you write better code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Flutter linter is a tool that scans your code for potential problems and makes recommendations for fixes. Generally speaking, it's a good practice to have the linter active because it can aid in error detection and better code maintenance.**

However, if you want to disable the linter for some reason, you can do so by adding the following line at the top of your Flutter file:

```
// ignore: some_lint_rule
```

You can also disable the linter for a specific block of code by wrapping it in a `lint` comment.

For example:

```
/*lint
some_lint_rule: off
*/

// code that violates the some_lint_rule

/*lint
some_lint_rule: on
*/
```

Note: Remember that turning off the linter might cause problems with your code, so you should normally avoid doing so unless you have a strong reason.